# Best CPU for modelling high poly scenes in Blender (10 million polygons and more)

Tags: performance

Everybody working in blender knows, that on high poly scenes blender starts responding very bad and slow. If a scene contains 10 million polygons and more working in blender becomes nightmare. It's even impossible to move an object across the scene.
So my question is, what is the best CPU for modelling such high poly scenes. More threads but lower frequency, like xeon 26xx v3 for instance, or less threads and higher frequency, like 4770k.
The rendering will be on GPU.
Thanks.

Comment: I once had 4770k overclocked to 5Ghz on water. You won't still be able to do much on high-poly scenes. You need to find application that is well optimized, go inverst money in that instead of in hardware that Blender cannot fully utilize anyways. I think you are talking about sculpting, ZBrush Core is even not that expensive.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it depends on cpu clock speed and number of cores.

Comment: Of course there are examples of such scenes handled with Blender, like e.g. [Through the Woods](https://www.artstation.com/artwork/vXPEa) but maybe investing in that kind of hardware isn't worth it (while it should be  possible)

Comment: Thanks for this great example. Now i see high poly scenes possible in blender.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly this guide:
http://polycount.com/discussion/173350/upgrading-or-building-a-new-pc-this-is-the-thread-for-you

you need to buy more power per core CPU, that means in your exemple you must buy a 4770k

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand why 4770k? Because of this comment:
-The better a CPUs single threaded performance, the better it'll be for physics simulation & most modeling tools (bevel, extrude, etc.)
Well, im not going to do physics simulations. Just a lot of polygons. Do you have any tests? Or just web link to such tests?